# Generating Swagger documentation from existing Java code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, swagger

Is there a way to generate swagger documentation (in `YAML` format) from existing Java code?

I am currently using YAML file to generate Java API code, but I am interested whether the reversed process can be achieved. That is if I can generate a YAML file from the existing Java code?

Comment: Could you show some examples as to what you're trying to achieve? Do you mean JavaDoc generation, setters/getters, etc.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The process for generating swagger definition from existing code is simple.

Add the following dependencies (I happen to use Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This adds a `swagger-ui` in your application that can be accessed with

```
http://<host>:<port>/swagger-ui.html
```

[image]

Hit the API documentation ([/v2/api-docs](http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs)) link and you will get a JSON file that can be easily converted to YAML file using http://editor.swagger.io (Edit -> Convert to YAML)

Comment: Is there any way to automate this process? For example, I want this yaml file to be generated when I build the project.

Comment: @RamPatra
Have you seen https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X and https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @GermanFaller yes, I am using these two in my project and it generates the swagger-ui for me but I haven't been able to figure out the way to generate the yaml file automatically as well.

Comment: Maybe I will write a post to show how to do this. Have you look on http://localhost:8080/<MyApp>/<Rest Endpoint>/swagger.yaml ?  forget <MyApp>, if you have your app on root.

Comment: No, it gives me a 404 error, unfortunately. I am able to access the Swagger UI at `http://localhost:9020/swagger-ui.html` but when I try to access `http://localhost:9020/swagger.yaml` I get a 404 error.

Comment: @RamPatra check what version of `springfox-swagger2` you are using it could be because of that. Also, look for the latest documentation.

Comment: @Vishrant I am using the latest version `2.9.2` (also, see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2). Btw, which version are you using? Also, are you seeing the yaml file at the url I mentioned above?

Comment: @RamPatra the ask was to generate the yaml file, not sure why I would see swagger.yaml file. You might already have swagger.yaml in your project structure which is being returned in the response, but as per this question, the swagger.yaml has to be generated. I was using `2.9.2` for this.