# Is it possible to discover endpoint parameters in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices, service-discovery

I have a Spring Boot application exposing some endpoints for REST requests. I am trying to decouple two components (which currently call each other's code directly), and I want them to make REST requests to each other (for an eventual microservice implementation). I know endpoint discovery can be done through a discovery service (e.g. Eureka), but is there a way to also communicate parameter information from the service which requires it to the client requesting it? 
Example: I have a shopping cart service which relies on information about products available for purchase. Using Eureka (or another service discovery tool) I can register my services so that the shopping cart service is now aware of the product service. If the product service has something like:

```
@GetMapping("/product")
public Product findById(@RequestParam int id) {
  return products.find(id);
}
```

I know to use this endpoint to get product with ID 3 the cart service would have to make a request to http://localhost:1234/product?id=3, but is there a way that it can discover these parameters and their required types at run time? In my example, if I use Eureka, the shopping cart service is dynamically made aware of the product service's location, but is not made aware of the parameters that its endpoints will accept. I know Spring Boot Actuator is supposed to provide this information, but whenever I use it, the params field for my endpoints is always empty.

Comment: can you make use of swagger?

Comment: @Vishrant Would Swagger allow the information to be exposed at the application level? I've used it in the browser to test my APIs, but I've never leveraged it in one service to get information about another.

Comment: not sure what you meant by "application level", but you can expose your API through `Swagger` in the form of `JSON` (then you can parse it in your application), check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511473/2704032, the `JSON` will be available through this end point `http://<host>:<port>/v2/api-docs`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way that it can discover these parameters and their required types at run time?

Do you really need this information at runtime?

Because it would be much simpler if you need this at development time. Then you could just use something like [Swagger](https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/), which will provide a service specification endpoint. It can even generate a client for your service.

But, if you really want it at runtime, you may be better served with a HATEOAS API. HATEOAS (Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State) means that your API is navigable. That means that clients can "crawl" you API following the links presented, like a human navigating through a website. How useful it will be, depend on what you are trying to achieve.

There are two popular "solutions" to this:

- [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) (Hypertext Application Language) - Still an Internet Draft
- [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org) (JSON for Linking Data) - A W3C Standard

Spring Boot has HAL support, see [spring-boot-starter-hateoas](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/).

Comment: I've used Swagger for testing my endpoints in-browser before, but I've never tried to use it to expose endpoint information to different services. Do you know if that's possible? I suppose it's not so much that this information needs to be processed at run-time, more so that I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this than baking endpoint information into the code directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter map, that will be dynamically populated with all used parameters:

```
@GetMapping("/product")
public Product findById(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams) {
 return products.find(allRequestParams.get("id"));
}
```

You can iterate the parameter map to find which parameters are present.

Comment: The parameter map is passed from the client to the service, no? I'm wondering if it's possible to make it such that the client discovers what parameters the service endpoint has available? For instance, in the above example, the /product endpoint requires an ID parameter passed. Is there a way for my shopping cart which calls the /product endpoint to know what parameters it needs to pass ahead of time? Basically i guess I'm wondering how to best do the inverse of your solution.

Comment: @Matteo Gallinucci thanks for posting your answers, I have the same feeling for swagger that I posted in the comment section, but what is the need to posting 2 answers in the same post? can you combine them in 1?

Comment: @Vishrant why? They are completely different answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) in your product service to generate apis, exposed in a json file. For example you can look at sample project [petstore](https://petstore.swagger.io/) with its [json exposed](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json), containing apis and parameters with definition.

Then in your shopping cart service you can navigate at runtime product service apis, iterating for specific api parameters.